# Crear un cronjobs en linux

Tags: linux, crontab

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito agregar un cronjob en mi servidor linux, lo he agregado pero no se ejecuta :c lo que  quiero ejecutar es un generador de feed que asocia mis productos con los de facebook, el módulo que uso para eso me da las siguientes instrucciones:

Comando (el script que generará el feed)
El comando para generar el Feed es:

```
curl -l -k "https://mipagina.com/facebookproducts/generate.php?fpf_secret_key=seriedenumerosyletras" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Ejemplo:

Ejecutar cada tres horas (0,3,6,9...)

```
0 */3 * * * curl -l -k "https://mipagina.com/facebookproducts/generate.php?fpf_secret_key=seriedenumerosyletras" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Usando la ruta de la secuencia de comandos
Si en algún caso necesita ingresar la ruta al script, use este:
`/var/www/html/facebookproducts/generate.php?fpf_secret_key=seriedenumerosyletras`

me he estado guiando del siguiente documento
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/es/articles/215767047-Crear-un-Cron-Job-personalizado

empiezo por ejecutar lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahí ya tengo guardado la instrucción, pero no hace la ejecución pasada las tres horas :/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

posteriormente procedo a ejecutar lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me dice que **no crontab for root**

¿me podrían apoyar por favor? de antemano gracias

Comment: Lo primero que te recomendaria es que pongas la ruta completa a curl (`/usr/bin/curl` o algo asi? Mira con `which curl` en caso de dudas) en vez de solo `curl`.

Comment: No es `nano crontab -e`. Es solo `crontab -e`.

Comment: el error esta en tu intruccion para editar, con `nano crontab -e` solo llamas a un archivo llamado `crontab -e` debes hacer el comando `crontab -e` solo... que indica que vas a editarlo o `nano crontab` creas el archivo lo guardas y luego `crontab < crontab` que indica que cargaras el crontab con un archivo llamado crontab